# sending files from flutter to spring webflux

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, flutter, spring-webflux

I'm trying to send files from flutter using Dio package it works fine while sending one file to spring but it shows 400 bad requests with multiple files
I'm using spring webflux
Note that: I tested this method with Postman  and it works fine
I searched about this but I got nothing
any help

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/uploadfiles/{type}", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public Mono<String> uploadMultipleFile(@RequestPart("files") Flux<FilePart> filePartFlux,
        @PathVariable("type") String type) {
    propertymediaIds = new ArrayList<>();
    Mono<String> then = filePartFlux.flatMap(it -> {
        try {
            Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("test", it.filename());
            AsynchronousFileChannel channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(tempFile, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
            DataBufferUtils.write(it.content(), channel, 0).doOnComplete(() -> {
            }).subscribe();
            try {
                File f = tempFile.toFile();
                byte[] bArray = Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath());
                Propertymedia propertymedia = new Propertymedia();
                propertymedia.setBlob(bArray);
                propertymedia.setBlobContentType(type);
                Mono<ResponseEntity<Propertymedia>> savedpropertymedia = createPropertymedia(propertymedia);
                Mono<String> id = savedpropertymedia.map(user -> user.getBody().getId());
                id.subscribe(v -> {
                    System.out.println(v);
                    if (v != null) {
                        this.propertymediaIds.add(v);
                        System.out.println(this.propertymediaIds);
                    }
                });
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Mono.just(propertymediaIds);
    }).then(Mono.just("OK"));
    return then;
}
```

this for loading image

```
Future<void> loadAssets() async {
List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();

List<File> fikles = List<File>();
String error = 'No Error Detected';
try {
  resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
    maxImages: 6,
    enableCamera: true,
    selectedAssets: images,
    cupertinoOptions: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
    materialOptions: MaterialOptions(
      actionBarColor: "#abcdef",
      actionBarTitle: "Example App",
      allViewTitle: "All Photos",
      useDetailsView: false,
      selectCircleStrokeColor: "#000000",
    ),
  );

  for (Asset i in resultList) {
    File f = new File(i.getByteData().toString());
    print(f.path);
  }
} on Exception catch (e) {
  error = e.toString();
}
// If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
// message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
// setState to update our non-existent appearance.
if (!mounted) return;

setState(() {
  images = resultList;
  _error = error;
});
```

}

this for sending image to spring

```
Future<File> uploadImage() async {
try {
  List<MultipartFile> multipart = List<MultipartFile>();
  for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var path =
        await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(images[i].identifier);
    multipart.add(
        await MultipartFile.fromFile(path, filename: 'myfile${i}.jpg'));
  }
  FormData imageFormData = FormData.fromMap({
    "files": multipart,
  });
  print('Bearer ' + _userService.token);
  Response response =
      await Dio().post("http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/uploadfiles/image",
          options: Options(headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + _userService.token,
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }),
          data: imageFormData);
  print("File upload response: $response");
  print('done');
} catch (e) {
  print("Exception Caught: $e");
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: there are several faults in your code, you should never subscribe in your own application. The one that initiates the call, the client (your flutter application), is the subscriber, your application is a publisher. Your application is basically acting like a client to itself, because it is subscribing to itself at two places.

You are basically coding imperatively in a reactive application, with all the try catches, and your subscribing to get the concrete values. And then in the end doing a `Mono.just` with the result.